# can´t fit dbinom for log regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, poisson, mle

I've been trying to fit a four parameter log regression using dbinom.
The four parameter log regression is expressed as: F(x) = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(x)/c))), where d=lower asymptote (ymin), a+d=upper asymptote, b=inflection point, , c=slope.
My response variable is a ratio from a mammal survey data set,(Patch_richness/Richness_proportion), "y" takes values from 0 to 1 (0.8, 0.4, 0.25......). my objective is to compare glm.null model, glm and the four parameter log regression by AIC to find which of the three fits best. Had no problem when running the function for a y=count (Patch_Richness) using dpois, and then just replace coeff values when plotting the curve:

```
library(bbmle)
cerrado = read.csv("data_stack.csv")
attach(cerrado)
logip = function(p,lambda,x){
  a = p[1]
  b = p[2]
  c = p[3]
  d = p[4]
  Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(FOREST500+km))/c)))
  -sum(dpois(x,lambda=Riq1, log=TRUE))
}
parnames(logip) = c("a","b","c","d")

modTR.log = mle2(minuslog = logip, start = c(a = 5,b = 72,c = 3,d = 0.1), data  = list(x = Patch_Richness))
summary(modTR.log)
plot(FOREST500,Patch_Richness, xlab = "Forest cover", ylab = "Patch Richness")#original data
curve (-0.29382+(4.95218/(1+exp((118.34117-x)/60.30478))), add=T)
```

But I'm having trouble when trying to fit this function for `y = proportion` (Richness_prop)

```
logip = function(p, lambda, x){
  a = p[1]
  b = p[2]
  c = p[3]
  d = p[4]
  Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(FOREST500 + km))/c)))
  -sum(dbinom(x,18,0.5,log = FALSE))
}
parnames(logip) = c("a","b","c","d")

modTR.log = mle2(minuslog = logip, start = c(a = 1,b = 72,c = 1,d = 0), data = list(x = Richness_prop))

summary(modTR.log)
AIC(modTR.log)
```

The model runs only when `log = FALSE`, (with warnings regarding non-integer values), but the summary output gives as coeff values the exact same number as the initial starting values, no matter the number in the starting values. So I guess something is really bad with this. Am I setting dbinom parameters right? Why does it only runs with `log=FALSE`?

[data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e_XOgTv1flSFFleHSwUJJPBzBdd9VPXRaZc2oukwtrE/edit#gid=0)

Really appreciate some help
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've run your first part, but I wonder if your model is OK? I don't see a good fit between the data and your model. Also, your logip function had an unnecessary argument "lambda", as it is computed by yourself.
Could you please use this code, and explain what made you think this one is working? Because I see a model of which two parameters could not be clearly found?

```
logip = function(p,x){
  a = p[1]
  b = p[2]
  c = p[3]
  d = p[4]
  Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(FOREST500+km))/c)))
  -sum(dpois(x,lambda=Riq1, log=TRUE))

parnames(logip) = c("a","b","c","d")

modTR.log = mle2(minuslog = logip, start=list(a=5, b=72,c=3,d=0.1), data=list(x = 
                 Patch_Richness), vecpar=TRUE)

summary(modTR.log)
coef_fit = coef(modTR.log)
plot(FOREST500,Patch_Richness, xlab = "Forest cover", ylab = "Patch Richness")
curve (coef_fit["d"]+(coef_fit["a"]/(1+exp((coef_fit["b"]-x)/coef_fit["d"]))), add=T)
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ran your code and it works exactly the same as mine. Same output. I understand the unnecessary lambda and I know it might look a bad fit, this is just one of many models I have run and compare. I don´t fully understand your question, but what I want to do is to estimate those coeff for a proportion: "y" takes values from 0 to 1 (0.8, 0.4, 0.25......). I assumed I had to use dbinom instead of dpois, but I'm having problems and I'm not sure if I can do something like this fir the data:

Comment: ```logip=function(p,x){
  a=p[1]
  b=p[2]
  c=p[3]
  d=p[4]
  Riq1 = d+(a/(1+exp((b-(FOREST2500+km))/c)))
  -sum(dbinom(x,size=18,p=Riq1,log=TRUE))
}
parnames(logip)=c("a","b","c","d")

modTR.log=mle2(minuslog=logip, start= c(a=0.8,b=20,c=1,d=0.1), 
               data=list(x=(Richness_prop)))
```

Comment: You're basically doing a logistic regression using MLE, right? I'd first use some dummy data generated from an exact model in the model family you want to fit with to ensure that the fitting works as you want.